# ¿Como puedo obtener el numero total de ids sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tendría una tabla como esta

| Id1 | Id2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 224 |
| 1 | 235 |
| 1 | 286 |
| 1 | 207 |
| 1 | 256 |
| 2 | 267 |

Y necesitaría hacer una query que me devolviera:

| Id1 | Id2 | N_total |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 224 | 5 |
| 1 | 235 | 5 |
| 1 | 286 | 5 |
| 1 | 207 | 5 |
| 1 | 256 | 5 |
| 2 | 267 | 1 |

La nueva columna debería de darme el numero de veces que aparece el id1.

He probado esto:

```
WITH T as (
SELECT 
    ID1, 
    ID2,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID1 ORDER BY ID2 DESC) AS Total
FROM T1 
)select 
    MAX(Total) AS Total,
    ID1, 
    ID2
FROM T
GROUP BY ID1, ID2;
```

Comment: Qué has intentado? Nos puedes compartir el SQL que has escrito para intentar resolver el problema? Porque, a como está, parece que deseas que alguie más te lo solucione

Comment: Deseo que alguien me ayude si se le ocurre una solución se lo agradecería, he estado probando varias cosas. Esa no sería realmente la tabla que tengo pero he probado a sacar eso y alomejor usando una tabla temporal con with sacar esa columna pero no se si se podría hacer o como puedo hacerlo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

De hecho, la solución es más sencilla y solo tienes que usar la función correcta.

```
SELECT 
    ID1, 
    ID2,
    COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY ID1) AS Total
FROM T1;
```

Comment: Genial! muchas gracias me ha sido muy util